# GridView Combobox DataBinding WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, combobox, datagrid

I am facing some problems with databinding with Combobox inside of DataGrid in WPF XAML.

I have Signal Class which has ObservableCollection.

```
public struct RawVal
{
    public string name;  //Name of the Value
    public int value;    // Value
}


public class Signal
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public Int32 Value { get; set; }
    public ObservableCollection<RawVal> rawValue { get; set; }
};
```

And in Stettings window there are

```
public partial class Settings : Window
{      
  public ObservableCollection<Signal> tempSigList { get; set; }
  public ObservableCollection<RawVal> tempRawVal { get; set; }
  .........
  .........
this.grdSignal.ItemsSource = tempSigList;
```

}

And my XAML looks like this:

```
<DataGrid ItemsSource="{Binding}" Name="grdSignal">
 <DataGrid.Columns>    
    <DataGridTemplateColumn Header="   RAW Value ">
      <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
          <DataTemplate>
              <ComboBox ItemsSource="{Binding tempRawVal  }" SelectedItem="Binding name" />
           </DataTemplate>
         </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
       </DataGridTemplateColumn>
  </DataGrid.Columns>
</DataGrid>
```

But no any results ㅠㅠㅠ
I have tried many examples on stackoverflow but, no any results.
Any suggestions or solutions are welcomed.
Thank you

Comment: Thank you Brothers.  It seems there is other problem. Comboboxes in other projects also do not show any item. It drops down but nothing on it. I am using .NET Framework 4.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here:

Window:

```
private void Window_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    tempSigList = new ObservableCollection<Signal>();
    tempSigList.Add(new Signal { Name = "Name 1", Value = 1, rawValue = new ObservableCollection<RawVal> { new RawVal { name = "combo 1", value = 1 }, new RawVal { name = "combo 2", value = 2 } } });
    tempSigList.Add(new Signal { Name = "Name 2", Value = 2, rawValue = new ObservableCollection<RawVal> { new RawVal { name = "combo 3", value = 3 }, new RawVal { name = "combo 4", value = 4 } } });
    tempSigList.Add(new Signal { Name = "Name 3", Value = 3, rawValue = new ObservableCollection<RawVal> { new RawVal { name = "combo 5", value = 5 }, new RawVal { name = "combo 6", value = 6 } } });
    tempSigList.Add(new Signal { Name = "Name 4", Value = 4, rawValue = new ObservableCollection<RawVal> { new RawVal { name = "combo 7", value = 7 }, new RawVal { name = "combo 8", value = 8 } } });
    tempSigList.Add(new Signal { Name = "Name 5", Value = 5, rawValue = new ObservableCollection<RawVal> { new RawVal { name = "combo 9", value = 9 }, new RawVal { name = "combo 10", value = 10 } } });

    dataGrid1.ItemsSource = tempSigList;
}
```

XAML:

```
<DataGrid x:Name="dataGrid1" ItemsSource="{Binding}">
    <DataGrid.Columns>
        <DataGridTemplateColumn Header="RAW Value">
            <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <ComboBox ItemsSource="{Binding rawValue}"  SelectedItem="{Binding name}" DisplayMemberPath="name" />
                </DataTemplate>
            </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
        </DataGridTemplateColumn>
    </DataGrid.Columns>
</DataGrid>
```

[image]

I used `AutoGenerateColumns=true`. You can make it `false` and have only your `ComboBox` column to show up.

[image]

Comment: Thank You Bro, It worked well. The problem was public struct RawVal members did not have getter and setter.

Comment: Yeah, i used a class with public properties and ended up forgetting to tell you about it...:O)

Answer (score 0):

First of all, Binding works with properties and not fields as in your class RawVal.

Showing the data using 3 columns as they should be :

```
public partial class Win32599087 : Window
    {
        public ObservableCollection<Signal> tempSigList { get; set; }
        public ObservableCollection<RawVal> tempRawVal { get; set; }

        public Win32599087()
        {
            InitializeComponent();

            tempRawVal = new ObservableCollection<RawVal>() { 
                new RawVal(){ Name="RawName1", Value=1},
                new RawVal(){ Name="RawName2", Value=2},
                new RawVal(){ Name="RawName3", Value=3},
                new RawVal(){ Name="RawName4", Value=4}

            };

            tempSigList = new ObservableCollection<Signal>() {             
                new Signal(){Name="signal1", Value = 1, RawValues = tempRawVal}
            };

            SignalGrid.DataContext = tempSigList;
        }
    }
```

//////////////

```
    <DataGrid x:Name="SignalGrid" AutoGenerateColumns="False" SelectedIndex="0" ItemsSource="{Binding}">
        <DataGrid.Columns>                

          <DataGridTextColumn Header="Name" Binding="{Binding Name}"/>
          <DataGridTextColumn Header="Value" Binding="{Binding Value}"/>
          <DataGridComboBoxColumn Header="RawValues">
            <DataGridComboBoxColumn.EditingElementStyle>
                <Style TargetType="ComboBox">
                    <Setter Property="ItemsSource" Value="{Binding Path=RawValues}" />
                    <Setter Property="DisplayMemberPath" Value="Name" />
                    <Setter Property="SelectedValuePath" Value="Value" />
                </Style>
              </DataGridComboBoxColumn.EditingElementStyle>
          </DataGridComboBoxColumn>

        </DataGrid.Columns>
    </DataGrid>
```

///////
With templatecolumn :

```
<DataGrid x:Name="SignalGridWithTemplates" AutoGenerateColumns="False" SelectedIndex="0" ItemsSource="{Binding}">
            <DataGrid.Columns>

                <DataGridTextColumn Header="Name" Binding="{Binding Name}"/>
                <DataGridTextColumn Header="Value" Binding="{Binding Value}"/>
                <DataGridTemplateColumn Header="RawValues">
                    <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                        <DataTemplate>
                            <StackPanel>
                                <ComboBox ItemsSource="{Binding RawValues}">
                                    <ComboBox.ItemTemplate>
                                        <DataTemplate>
                                            <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                                                <TextBlock Text="{Binding Name}" Background="AliceBlue"/>
                                                <TextBlock Text=" | "/>
                                                <TextBlock Text="{Binding Value}" Background="Azure"/>
                                            </StackPanel>
                                        </DataTemplate>
                                    </ComboBox.ItemTemplate>
                                </ComboBox>
                            </StackPanel>
                        </DataTemplate>
                    </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                </DataGridTemplateColumn>

            </DataGrid.Columns>
        </DataGrid>
```

Comment: Read this blog entry : [DataGrid layout](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/vinsibal/archive/2008/08/14/wpf-datagrid-dissecting-the-visual-layout.aspx)